# How to remove the java script variable refrences

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var depe = {}

var array1 = [];
array1.push('value1');

var array2 = [];
array2.push('value1a');
array2.push('value2');

depe['key1'] = array1;
depe['key2'] = array2;   // now variable depe contains {"key1":["value1"],"key2":["value1a","value2"]}


var temp = depe['key2'];  // now variable temp contains ["value1a","value1a"]
temp[temp.length] = 'newValue' // now variable temp contains ["value1a","value1a","newValue"]
```

After execution of last line variable `depe` contains

```
{"key1":["value1"],"key2":["value1a","value2","newValue"]}
```

I don't want to be updated in variable `depe`. How do I resolve it ?

Comment: `I don't want to be updated in variable depe` Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think that if `temp` is changed then `depe` is changed too.

Comment: You need to make copies of the objects and put them into `depe`, otherwise you're referring to them by their reference and they'll be updated everywhere.

Comment: Use `depe['key1'] = array1.slice(0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, arrays are passed around by reference so if you assign `var temp = depe['key2'];` and then add another item to `temp` it is changing the one and only one array so it will show in both places.

To make a separate shallow copy of an array that you can change, you have to make an explicit copy which you can do with `array.slice(0)`:

```
// get a copy of the array in depe['key2']
// that I can change independently of what is in depe
var temp = depe['key2'].slice(0);
temp[temp.length] = 'newValue';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone objects in javascript.

Please read: http://jsperf.com/cloning-an-object/2

or

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

from: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Except what this OP wants a copy of is an array which can be shallow copied with just `array.slice(0)`.

Answer (score -1):

you need to clone your array

```
    function cloneArray(array){
      var newArray = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
       newArray[i] = cloneValue(array[i]);
      }
      return newArray;
    }
```

to clone a value

```
   function cloneValue(value){
     if (typeof value != 'object')
        return value;
     else {
       var newObj = {};
     for (var prop in value){
      newObj[prop] = value[prop];
    }
    return newObj;
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
 var arr2 = cloneArray(arr1);
```

Comment: See @jfriend00 answer. This can be done with `array.slice(0)`.

Answer (score -1):

i think u should use slice() method to get a clone of depe array. you can read this for your reference : [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)
OR u can make this prototype function:

```
Array.prototype.clone = function() {
return this.slice(0);
```

};

so in line : var temp = depe['key2'];

u can use depe['key2'].clone() instead of depe['key2'].slice(0)

Hope this help you.

Comment: It is a bit dangerous to add enumerable methods to the Array object because if/when someone does a `for (key in array)` enumeration of the array (which isn't the proper way to enumerate an array, but is done far too often), then `"clone"` will come up as an item in the array.